# how to show CSS loading while calling ajax on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have Drop-down button in my html table and it have 2 links on clicking on link1 i am forwarding to a new page where i am making an ajax call to show data in an HTML table, but that data is in large amount so what i am trying to achieve is to show an css loader until the data loaded fully

here is my code which is having the drop-down button and css loader. what i want to do  is on clicking the link i want to show the loader and show the HTML table in Background so that no one can click or edit the table until the new page is loaded

```js
 var currentlyClickedOutlet = "";
     var currentlyClickedBilldate="";
     $(document).ready(function (){
       $dropdown = $("#contextMenu");
       $(".actionButton").click(function() {
         //move dropdown menu
         $(this).after($dropdown);
         //update links
         $(this).dropdown();
 
          currentlyClickedOutlet = $(this).attr("data-place");
         currentlyClickedBilldate = $(this).attr("data-plac"); 
         
       });
      
  
      $('.loader').hide();
     
     $('.link1').click(function (e) {
      
       $('.loader').show();
     });
    
    

    
     
    });

    data = [
            {
                "amount": 476426,
                "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 92141,
                "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 115313,
                "billdate": "2018-09-01",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 511153,
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 115704,
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 83597,
                "billdate": "2018-09-02",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 167421,
                "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 53775,
                "billdate": "2018-09-03",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 269712,
                "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
              },
              {
                "amount": 58850,
                "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
              },
              {
                "amount": 82999,
                "billdate": "2018-09-04",
                "outlet": "KOLAR"
              }
            ]

    let formatData = function(data) {

      let billdates = [];
      let outlets = [];
      data.forEach(element => {
        if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
          billdates.push(element.billdate);
        }
        if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
          outlets.push(element.outlet);
        }
      });
      return {
        data: data,
        billdates: billdates,
        outlets: outlets,

      };
    };



    let renderTable = function(data, divId, filterdata) {
      billdates = data.billdates;
      outlets = data.outlets;
      data = data.data;
      let tbl = document.getElementById(divId);
      let table = document.createElement("table");
      let thead = document.createElement("thead");
      let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
      let th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = "Bill_____Date";
      th.classList.add("text-center");
      headerRow.appendChild(th);
      let grandTotal = 0;
      let outletWiseTotal = {};
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = "Total1";
      th.classList.add("text-center");
      headerRow.appendChild(th);

      outlets.forEach(element => {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = element;
        th.classList.add("text-center");
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
        outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
        data.forEach(el => {
          if (el.outlet == element) {
            outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
          }
        });
        grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
      });


      thead.appendChild(headerRow);
      headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = "Total";
      th.classList.add("text-center");

      headerRow.appendChild(th);

      outlets.forEach(element => {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element];
        th.classList.add("text-right"); 
        headerRow.appendChild(th);
      });
    
      th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = grandTotal;
      th.classList.add("text-right"); // grand total
      
      headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
      thead.appendChild(headerRow);
      table.appendChild(thead);

      let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
     
      billdates.forEach(element => {
        let row = document.createElement("tr");
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = element;
        row.appendChild(td);
        let total = 0;
        
        outlets.forEach(outlet => {
          let el = 0;
          data.forEach(d => {
            if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
              total += parseInt(d.amount);
              el = d.amount;
            }
          });
         



          td = document.createElement("td");
          a = document.createElement("a");
         
          td.classList.add("text-right");
          td.classList.add("dropdown");
          a.classList.add("btn");
          a.classList.add("btn-secondary");
          a.classList.add("actionButton");
          a.classList.add("btn")
          a.classList.add("btn-secondary");
          a.classList.add("dropdown-toggle");
          a.classList.add("dropdown-toggle-split");
         
          
         /*  a.classList.add("text-center"); */

          a.setAttribute("data-place", outlet);
          a.setAttribute("data-plac", element);
         
          
        
          a.setAttribute("data-toggle", "dropdown");
          a.innerHTML = el;
          td.appendChild(a); 

          row.appendChild(td);



          
        });
        
       
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = total;
        td.classList.add("text-right"); 
       
        row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
        tbody.appendChild(row);

      });

      table.appendChild(tbody);

      tbl.innerHTML = "";
      tbl.appendChild(table);
      table.classList.add("table");
      table.classList.add("table-striped");
      table.classList.add("table-bordered");
      table.classList.add("table-hover");
    }
    let formatedData = formatData(data);
    renderTable(formatedData, 'tbl', '');
```

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}



@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
 <script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div class="loader"></div>   <!-- this will show the loader  -->




  
 <div id="tbl"></div>
  
    <ul id="contextMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="test.jsp" class="link1 dropdown-item">BillSummary</a></li>
        <li><a href="test1.jsp" class="link2 dropdown-item">Category wise Summary</a></li>
    </ul>
```

after clicking on link one of the above snippet i am going to a new page where i am making an ajax call to get data.

what i want to do is show the `CSS`loader after clicking on link1 until the new page fully loaded
and then hide it after the new page fully loaded

my other page where i am making the ajax call is

here i am putting static data in form of JSON so that any one can try my code, but in my code i will make an ajax call

```js
/* i will makeajax call in place of json like this   
                      
                       $.ajax({
  url : "TestServlet",
  method : "GET",
  dataType : "json",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data : {
      fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
               todate : $("#enddate").val(),
            outlet : $("#all").val()
            
    },
    
  success : function(tableValue) {
   
        console.log("test",tableValue);
     
         addTable(tableValue)
  
   
    
  }
    
 });
                      
                      */


var tableValue=[
                
                   
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22364",
                     "AMOUNT": 79,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22365",
                     "AMOUNT": 36,
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22366",
                     "AMOUNT": 221,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22367",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22368",
                     "AMOUNT": 79,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22369",
                     "AMOUNT": 84,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22370",
                     "AMOUNT": 267,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22371",
                     "AMOUNT": 84,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22372",
                     "AMOUNT": 140,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22373",
                     "AMOUNT": 89,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22374",
                     "AMOUNT": 202,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22375",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22376",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22377",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22378",
                     "AMOUNT": 118,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22379",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22380",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22381",
                     "AMOUNT": 71,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22382",
                     "AMOUNT": 47,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22383",
                     "AMOUNT": 26,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22384",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22385",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22386",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22387",
                     "AMOUNT": 79,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22388",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22389",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22390",
                     "AMOUNT": 95,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22391",
                     "AMOUNT": 126,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22392",
                     "AMOUNT": 231,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22393",
                     "AMOUNT": 142,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22394",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22395",
                     "AMOUNT": 26,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22396",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22397",
                     "AMOUNT": 142,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22398",
                     "AMOUNT": 62,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22399",
                     "AMOUNT": 95,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22400",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22401",
                     "AMOUNT": 80,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22402",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22403",
                     "AMOUNT": 89,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22404",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22405",
                     "AMOUNT": 58,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22406",
                     "AMOUNT": 147,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22407",
                     "AMOUNT": 80,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22408",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22409",
                     "AMOUNT": 140,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22410",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22411",
                     "AMOUNT": 100,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22412",
                     "AMOUNT": 58,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22413",
                     "AMOUNT": 142,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22414",
                     "AMOUNT": 47,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22415",
                     "AMOUNT": 47,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22416",
                     "AMOUNT": 95,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22417",
                     "AMOUNT": 26,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22418",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22419",
                     "AMOUNT": 192,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22420",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22421",
                     "AMOUNT": 70,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22422",
                     "AMOUNT": 70,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22423",
                     "AMOUNT": 84,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22424",
                     "AMOUNT": 121,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22425",
                     "AMOUNT": 95,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22426",
                     "AMOUNT": 47,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22427",
                     "AMOUNT": 147,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22428",
                     "AMOUNT": 76,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22429",
                     "AMOUNT": 84,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22430",
                     "AMOUNT": 42,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22431",
                     "AMOUNT": 89,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22432",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22433",
                     "AMOUNT": 47,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22434",
                     "AMOUNT": 47,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22435",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22436",
                     "AMOUNT": 26,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22437",
                     "AMOUNT": 189,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22438",
                     "AMOUNT": 63,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22439",
                     "AMOUNT": 37,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22440",
                     "AMOUNT": 77,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   },
                   {
                     "BILLNO": "D22441",
                     "AMOUNT": 53,
                     "COUNTER": "Fast Food"
                   }
                   
                 ]
    
    
    function addTable(tableValue) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]); // get all the keys from first
    
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length; // count all which
               // are number
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum); // cut five elements from frist
  col = col.concat(num); // shift the first item to last
  // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.


    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
           
      tr.appendChild(th);
  }

  // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
  for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
           var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];
    if(tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)){
      tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in')
    }
    tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
              
              if (j > 1)
             
              tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
              
      }
  }

  // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
   table.classList.add("table-striped");
   table.classList.add("table-bordered");
   
   
  }
                     
 addTable(tableValue)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 
 <script
  src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<div id="newTable"></div>
```

Comment: So you want to display a loader until the page has loaded (aka `window.onload` has fired) and the AJAX call is completed?

Comment: @somethinghere yupp until the new page full content is loaded.

Comment: append a loading id when the ajax call buttun is clicked, style in css and remove on success response

Comment: ajax({
   beforeSend: callback
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some CSS to display a little loader while the `body` has no `ready` class. Then simply wait for you ajax call to finish and add the class to your body. (I added your mock code in the error handler and reduced its duplication a bit so its simpler to keep track of and closer to your original intent).

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "TestServlet",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {
        fromdate : $("#startdate").val(),
        todate : $("#enddate").val(),
        outlet : $("#all").val()
    },  
    success: function( value ) {
        
        addTable( value );
        document.body.classList.add( 'ready' );
    
    },  
    error: function( error ) {
        
        // Lets do this to keep the mock data short
        const tableValue = [{ BILLNO: "D22364", AMOUNT: 79, COUNTER: "Fast Food"}];

        while( tableValue.length < 50 ) tableValue.push( Object.assign({}, tableValue[0]) );
    
        // Lets do this to guarantee a little delay
        // So you can at least see the loader as if it took some time.
        setTimeout(() => {
        
          addTable( tableValue );
          document.body.classList.add( 'ready' );
        
        }, 1000);
    
    }  
});

function addTable( tableValue ) {

    var col = Object.keys(tableValue[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    
        var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
        
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < tableValue.length; i++) {

      tr = table.insertRow(-1);

      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {

          var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
          var tabledata = tableValue[i][col[j]];

          if(tabledata && !isNaN(tabledata)){

              tabledata = parseInt(tabledata).toLocaleString('en-in');

          }

          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;

          if (j > 1) tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
  
        }
        
    }
    
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("newTable");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");

}
```

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotateZ(0deg); }
  to { transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotateZ(360deg); }
}

body:not(.ready){

  pointer-events: none;
  
}
body:not(.ready):before,
body:not(.ready):after {
  
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
}
body:not(.ready):before {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 1000000;
  
}
body:not(.ready):after {
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1000001;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<div id="newTable"></div>
```

Comment: hey yopur code is working fine...but i have an doubt

Comment: @viveksingh Ignore the timeout, I added a comment to that - its there to delay your 'error' call for a bit, otherwise the loader would barely flash in front of your eyes making you doubt whether its there. Its just there to simulate some delay expected with an actual JSON call.

Comment: ok fine thatt worked..but the issue when the loader is loading..the background menus  are active so in that scenario while loading the data user can click on other buttons also that i don't want

Comment: If you z-index of the `:before` and `:after` are high enough they should easily cover any clickable buttons and regions on the screen. I have used `1` and `2` as the z-indexes, but you could easily set it to `99999999` or something. Any events generated will then be generated on the `body` through those pseudo elements. You could also add `pointer-events: none` to the `body:not(.ready)` rule to prevent any events from being fired.

Comment: I have added the `pointer-events: none;` rule and increased the z-index on my snippet as well. This should prevent any interaction until it is ready.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184860/discussion-between-vivek-singh-and-somethinghere).

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need to show a loader div on the whole page till you get all the data from ajax call. You can show a loader div on the complete page with height and width set to 100%. Just change the display property to 'block' in the '.then' section of your ajax call and change it back to none at the end of your '.success' block of the ajax call.

Comment: any snippet you can provide?

Comment: https://makitweb.com/display-loading-image-when-ajax-call-is-in-progress/

Comment: You can take reference from here -

Comment: i am doing this only.but how can i hidethe back ground or de activate that while loading so user cannot be able to click on other buttons

Comment: If you loader window/div covers the whole screen, nothing will be clickable in the background. Just use height and width of the loader container as 100%

Answer (score 0):

What you need is full screen overlay.

```
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: this will not solve my solution i want to show the loader until the ajax call is completed

Comment: on `beforeSend` show overlay, on `complete` hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the loader either on page load or on the ajax call

```
    success : function(tableValue) {
       $(".loader").show();
    }
```

And remove the loader once the data is constructed on the DOM

```
      table.appendChild(tbody);
      $(".loader").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use blockUI plugin. It works fine as loader and can be configured

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/